# What's wrong with my relationsip into tables?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I'm setting relationship between tabels,all of that works ,without roles and users tables

I've alreade tried `primaryjoin()`, but it can't helps me 
when I try to do migrate ,error says

> `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'email'; check that column/key exists.`

Code:

```
class users(db.Model):
   id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
   username=db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True, index=True)
   email=db.Column(db.String(100),unique=True)
   password=db.Column(db.String(100))
   posts=db.relationship('posts',backref='user')
   comment=db.relationship('comment',backref='user_com')
   picture=db.Column(db.String(1000))
   role_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('roles.id'))


   def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
       super(users,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

   def __repr__(self):
       return 
        str({"id":self.id,"username":self.username,"email":self.email})


class roles(db.Model):
   id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
   name=db.Column(db.String(50),unique=True)
   users = db.relationship('users', backref='role',primaryjoin="roles.id 
         == users.role_id")

   def __init3__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(roles,self).__init3__(*args,**kwargs)

   def __repr3__(self):
        return'<roles id:{},name:{} >'.format(self.id,self.name)

 class posts(db.Model):

    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title=db.Column(db.String(100))
    content=db.Column(db.Text())
    image=db.Column(db.String(100))
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    comment=db.relationship('comment',backref='post_com')

    def __init1__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(posts,self).__init1__(*args,**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return'<posts id:{},title:{} >'.format(self.id,self.title)


 class comment(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    text=db.Column(db.String(200))
    post_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
    user_id=db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init2__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(comment,self).__init2__(*args,**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):

        return str({"id":self.id,"text":self.text})
```

for migration I write this into cmd

```
    python manage.py db init
    python manage.py db migrate
    python manage.py db upgrade
```

This is the full error

```
   sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: 
   (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 
   'email'; check that column/key exists
    [SQL:
     DROP INDEX email ON users]
      (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405))
```

This is the manage.py

```
from app import manager
from main import *
if __name__== '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

and this is app.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from config import Configuration
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate,MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Configuration)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager=Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db',MigrateCommand)
```

Comment: Is your database structure in sync with your model?

Comment: my database has already worked,until I try to insert roles

Comment: That did not aswer my question. What state is your database? Are there unapplied migration? How do your migrate? How do they look? What is the full error traceback? …

Comment: I'm doing migration in this way 
"""
python manage.py db init
python manage.py db migrate
python manage.py db upgrade
""""
and full error says 
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1091 (42000): Can't DROP 'email'; check that column/key exists
[SQL:
DROP INDEX email ON users]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

Comment: Add all code and error messages to the question. They are not readable in the commands.

Comment: Now You can see it

Comment: Can you add the file generated by `python manage.py db migrate`?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot  I've added it

Comment: Is there not a file in a folder called `migrations` that is generated when you run `python manage.py db migrate`? According to the docs it should generate a `.py` script

Comment: I have a folder named migrations and there have .py files and alembic versions of upgrade

Comment: I guess the error lies somewhere in those migration files. Share them and then we can help you :)

Comment: which file exactly ?
or all files in that folder?

Comment: One of the files should contain something like `op.drop_column('users', 'email')`, but in general it's good practice to review the generated file before applying a migration - often you'll find you need to add or change something. For example, I recently renamed a column and made it non-nullable, but the migration file opted to drop the old column and create a new one, which would have destroyed the data inside